# Dialog from jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have table with data form database. I write a code, when I clicked one item (td with id open) it's show popup window with more data from database. Problem is when i click first time didn't happened, but on next click this show me content matching to previously click. Where I go wrong in my code?

```
    $(document).on('click', 'td#open', function(){
      var name = $(this).text();

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:'page/degustacje_popup.php',
        data: {
          'name': name
        },
        success: function(data){
          //Set up the dialog box
          $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen  : false,
            modal     : true,
            resizable : false,
            width     : "750px",
            title     : "Degustacja",
            });

          $(document).on('click', '#open', function(){          
            $('.dialog_content').html(data);
            $('#dialog').dialog("open");
            });
            }
          });
    });
```

Comment: #open id is unique or multiple td have same id?

Comment: there are multiple td with the same id, my mistake, i replace id to class .open and remove the second click event and it's working, thanks

Comment: If my answer workable for you then +1 for me. cheers :D

Comment: i can't vote until I reach 15 points of reputation :(

Comment: okay once you reach . do that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## open id is unique or multiple td have same id?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', 'td[id="open"]', function(){
```

The `id` is specific; don't use same id for multiple element. Use class instead.